# Replace number in a specific path in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace, path, numbers

my question is pretty simple, but I can,t find my answer on the internet...
I have a path in an HTML file between a  bracket. My path is in a for loop and contains a number, which I want to increment. Here's my code. I want to replace the "1" with my i value in my for loop.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < comboboxesArrowDown.length; i++)
    {
        var comboboxArrowDown = comboboxesArrowDown[i];
        comboboxArrowDown.onclick = function () 
        {
            var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
            e.which = 39; // Right arrow key (Keycode #39)
            $("#AutresPlacements_Placements_1__Terme-Validation > .t-widget > .t-dropdown-wrap > .t-input").trigger(e);
        }
    }
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate the string using the value from the loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < comboboxesArrowDown.length; i++)
    {
        var comboboxArrowDown = comboboxesArrowDown[i];
        comboboxArrowDown.onclick = 

        (function (val) 
        {
            return function()
            {
                  var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
                  e.which = 39; // Right arrow key (Keycode #39)
                  $("#AutresPlacements_Placements_" + val + "__Terme-Validation > .t-widget > .t-dropdown-wrap > .t-input").trigger(e);
            }
        })(i)
    }
```